# Multiple values in a single assertion in webdriverio

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

Is it possible to add multiple possible values to a single expectation? As in my case the title might have different text values depending on other processes on the website (the code below does not work as I would want to).

```
it('card should have a one of two names', () => {
    expect(MyPage.cardName).toHaveText('Good Products' || 'Wonderfull Products');
});
```

The same question goes to chai's `deep.equal`. Is it possible to have multiple variants in one assertion?

```
it('should verify the card titles list', () => {
    // an array is created here
    const cardTitles = MyPage.cardTitlesText();
    chaiExpect(cardTitles).to.deep.equal(['Apples', 'Carrots', 'Tomatoes', 'Potatoes'] || ['Potatoes', 'Apples', 'Carrots', 'Tomatoes']);
});
```

Or perhaps I miss something in an overall concept of testing and this should be approached differently in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible in the latest version of built-in expect-webdriverio, just pass an array of strings, see https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect-webdriverio.html#tohavetext

Feel free ro raise feature requests to https://github.com/webdriverio/expect-webdriverio

Comment: [Mike G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2475987/mike-g), somehow this doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

Code:
`it("card should have a one of two names", () => {
    expect(MyPage.cardName).toHaveText(['Good Products', 'Wonderfull Products']);
});`

Result
`1) MayPage tests Product card should have a proper name
[chrome 87.0.4280.141 mac os x #0-0] Expect $(".card-header span[class="card-title"]") to have text

Expected: ["Good Products", "Wonderfull Products"]
Received: "Wonderfull Products"
`

Comment: Make sure to install the latest version of expect webdriverio

Answer (score 0):

```
'Good Products' || 'Wonderfull Products'
```

this basically means "if the operand on the left is false, return the value on the right". But you always have `Good Products` there, which will never evaluate to false.

Similarly with the array in the second example. This wouldn't evaluate to false even if you had an empty array:

```
[] || [4]
```

still returns `[]`.

It's all just JavaScript, so you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: [pavelsaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10401931/pavelsaman), thanks, I totally get what you're saying but WebdriverIO checks only the first value without taking the value on the right into account. How should I make WebdriverIO to take both values into account and pass the test if one of them corresponds to the value returned from the scrapped website? ( `a || b` is just a visual example of what I'm talking about)

Comment: I see. I don't think there's a direct support for that in WebdriverIO. Perhaps you can go for chai library and [`oneOf`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) method. I think that would be the most elegant and readable solution.